# Tensorflow shape issues in a very simple all-scalar situation

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

This SSCCE generates a shape error despite everything bieng a scalar:

```
import tensorflow as tf
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[1], name='x')
y = tf.add(x, 1.0)
feed = dict()
feed[x] = 0.0
with tf.Session() as sess:
    print('Simple:', sess.run(y, feed_dict=feed))

# ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape () for Tensor 'x:0', which has shape '(1,)'
```

What is the flaw in this code? Wrapping the 1.0 in tf.convert_to_tensor has no effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you might want to make your placeholder to have the shape of (), i.e. `tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=(), name='x')`.

Comment: Why isn't shape = [1] a scalar?

Comment: I used the term scalar more or less in the TF-sense, but yes I guess in math/physics, things which have shape=[1] can also be called scalars. From a programmer's point of view though, it's best we make shapes of the data fed and that of the placeholders consistent. What you're feeding there is essentially a numpy array of shape ().